# Swift: pass data to a segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I wanted to change the behaviour of my segue depending on which button I press. Both buttons open the sam VC, but with different colors and some more information are passed. But I also wanted to change the animation while opening the second VC.

Following a tutorial I made CustomSegue.swift with the class CustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue. In that class I have my animation functions and I would like to change how the view appears (from left or from right). To do so, I need to know which button was pressed to change the parameters.

How to make my custom segue class know which button was pressed?

Comment: A possible solution is to assign different tags to the buttons and pass the button as `sender`

Comment: How am I able then to get access to the sender in the CustomSegue class?

Comment: You call `performSegue` then the framework calls `prepareForSegue`, there you can make your settings before the transition is preformed.

Comment: I have done that. The problem is, beside passing data from one VC to another one, I want to pass data to my segue class. Because I have been following a tutorial for animating VC appearance and there I need to make a new CustomSegue which inherits from UIStoryboardSegue. The animations are performed there and I need some data there, not in the second VC

Comment: You didn't mention that the question is about a custom class. I have no clue what that class does.

Comment: Basically I want my customsegue class to know which button was pressed. In Qt I would send an additional signal with data, how am I able to do that here...

Comment: I won't down vote this question but others will. Please show what you've tried and explain why it doesn't work. Then we can help you figure out an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve it on my own now. By sending data over to my custom class in the prepare() function of my first VC. Now I am able to send the information which button was pressed. I thought to use it, you need to make a connection between two VCs, but looks like it can be used to send data between two classes too.